# Pass UITextView tag as a parameters in UITapGestureRecognizer in swift 5

Tags: swift, uilabel, swift4, swift5, uitapgesturerecognizer

Is there any way to pass **UITextView** **Tag** in UITapGestureRecognizer #**Selector** method in swift 5?

like below code

if yes -> How?
if no -> Why?

```
let txtView1Tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(textViewTapped(_:),tag: txtView1.tag))
let txtView2Tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(textViewTapped(_:), tag: txtView2.tag))

txtView1.addGestureRecognizer(txtView1Tap)
txtView2.addGestureRecognizer(txtView1Tap)
```

Answer (score 1):

No, because there is no API to do that.

But you can get the text view from the `UITapGestureRecognizer` with the `view` property

```
@obj func textViewTapped(_ sender : UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let textView = sender.view as! UITextView
    if textView.tag == ...
}
```

Comment: I would switch the `textView` and check `case txtView1: ...` instead of using tags